# How to register component in vue+ts correctly?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-component

I have this code:
*App.vue*

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <div>
      <schedule-table
      v-if = "schedule.length > 0"
      :exercises="schedule[0].exercises"
      />
    </div>
  </v-container>
</template>
<script lang="ts">

import Vue from "vue";
import { Component } from "vue-property-decorator";
import ScheduleTable from '@/components/ScheduleTable.vue'

@Component({
  components: {
    ScheduleTable,
  }
})
</script>
```

*ScheduleTable.vue*

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <schedule-week
    :exercises="exercises"
    />
  </v-container>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import { Component, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";
import { IExercise } from "@/interfaces"
import ScheduleWeek from '@/components/ScheduleWeek.vue'

@Component({
  name: 'ScheduleWeek',
  components: {
    ScheduleWeek,
  }
})

@Component
export default class ScheduleTable extends Vue {
  @Prop( {required: true, type: Array } ) readonly exercises!: IExercise;
}
</script>
```

*ScheduleWeek.vue*

```
<template>
  <v-container
  :ex="exercises"
  >
    here is tables (but this tables dosn't show and any other text dosn't show)
  </v-container>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import { Component, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";
import { IExercise } from "@/interfaces"


@Component
export default class ScheduleWeek extends Vue {
  @Prop( {required: true, type: Array } ) readonly exercises!: IExercise;
}
</script>
```

And have vue warn:

> Unknown custom element: < schedule-week > - did you register the
>   component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide
>   the "name" option.

**How to fix this problem? How to register component correctly?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are multiple ways to declare a vue-component when you use typescript. The class-based SFC approach (the one you are using) needs to follow a slightly different syntax. You used the typescript `decorator` twice in your schedule-week component

App.vue

```
<v-container>
    <div>
      <schedule-table
      v-if = "schedule.length > 0"
      :exercises="schedule[0].exercises"
      />
    </div>
  </v-container>
</template>
<script lang="ts">

import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator"; // you can import vue here
import ScheduleTable from '@/components/ScheduleTable.vue'

@Component({
  components: {
    ScheduleTable,
  }
})
export default class App extends Vue {} // the @Component() decorator needs to be followed by the exported class
```

Correspondingly your other components:

ScheduleTable.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <schedule-week
    :exercises="exercises"
    />
  </v-container>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator"; // see above
import { IExercise } from "@/interfaces"
import ScheduleWeek from '@/components/ScheduleWeek.vue'

@Component({
  name: 'ScheduleTable',
  components: {
    ScheduleWeek,
  }
}) // >>>don't use the decorator twice<<<
export default class ScheduleTable extends Vue {
  @Prop( {required: true, type: Array } ) readonly exercises!: IExercise;
}
</script>
```

ScheduleWeek.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container
  :ex="exercises"
  >
    here is tables (but this tables dosn't show and any other text dosn't show)
  </v-container>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator"; // see above
import { IExercise } from "@/interfaces"


@Component
export default class ScheduleWeek extends Vue {
  @Prop( {required: true, type: Array } ) readonly exercises!: IExercise;
}
</script>
```

##EDIT:

From the officiel TypeScript Documentation:

> With the introduction of Classes in TypeScript and ES6, there now exist certain scenarios that require additional features to support annotating or modifying classes and class members. Decorators provide a way to add both annotations and a meta-programming syntax for class declarations and members.

Decorators are basically TypeScript(JavaScript) functions which are used to add additional information to the following `class` (your component) or class members. This also means a decorator cannot stand alone. The `@Component()` decorator takes an `Object` as parameter which is 'as-is' translated into component-options.

Comment: I dont need to use decorator twice because it's include child-components defenition and defenition this class as a component? Do I understand it right?

Comment: The @Component decorator directly belongs to the following class definition. A stand-alone decorator has no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

To register the components `SubOne` and `SubTwo` in `MyComponent`, pass it to the `@Component` decorator:

```
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component({
  components: {
    SubOne,
    SubTwo,
  }
}) 
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  …
}
```

And make sure you also decorate the SubComponents like so;

```
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class SubOne extends Vue {
  …
}
```

## Error in @MarcRo's answer

### Setup and resulting Error

In the Component `ScheduleTable.vue`, the decorator `@Component` gets the parameter `name` set to the Component it is about to import. This leads to a recursive call of said Component and hence an Error.

### Fix

Set `name: 'ScheduleTable'` - or even drop it. The class name seems to be used (which is what we are doing).

## Aside

I could not find a doc on what can actually passed to the decorator, but it's used like this in @MarcRo's answer in `App.vue` as well as [here](https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/class-component.html#other-options). (The link in the comments there seems to be old).

I don't have enought reputation to comment and a fixing edit got rejected, so sorry for the extra post.

Thank you @MarcRo for teaching me how to use this and the facepalm moment after solving the recursion error after a way too long time ;)

Comment: You are absolutelty right; that should have been `scheduleTable` :)